# Sci-fi/time traveller cartoon where a time traveler on a training mission saves a girl from being killed which makes Earth disappear

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, cartoon, soft-sci-fi

Sci-fi/time traveller cartoon from the early to mid 2000's.

The plot goes like this:

A time traveler was in some sort of training mission. Whilst he was on this mission he witnesses this girl that was going to get killed (I think this was taking part during the French Revolution). He saves the girl but it somehow causes the Earth to just disappear as if it had never existed. After this they go on an journey to find out what happened.

I remember seeing it when I was growing up in Portugal and I think it either aired on [Panda or Panda Big](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canal_Panda).

Answer (score 5):

Elements of this sound like plot points from various Valérian comics, and apparently there was a 2007 animated series, *Time Jam: Valerian & Laureline*, that moved various of the elements around so sounds like a match. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Jam:_Valerian_%26_Laureline):

> The TV series differs from the original comics in that in the TV series Valerian comes from the year 2417 instead of 2720, and meets Laureline in the year 912 instead of 1000. Whereas in the comics Valerian takes Laureline back to his own time without any trouble, in the animated series this results in Earth disappearing from the solar system. The couple settle in the galactic capital Central Point and realize they are possibly the only humans left. They begin a new life as space mercenaries and adventurers, exploring the new space-time continuum while at the same time attempting to rediscover the Earth.

Comment: thank you Daniel, you dont know how long ive been looking for it, i can finally rest at night, thank you so much

Comment: @Gonzo: You can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.